# Updatation regarding moment bower components

Tags: momentjs, version, bower

Currently in my project the Moment.js version is 2.5
I want to upgrade it to the latest one i.e version 2.29

I tried to copy and replace the full code of Moment.js but still tools shows its version is 2.5

Please guide, how to do the same.